# How can i solve my code to check size of data type (is c language with gcc compiler) on linux mint

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-warnings, format-specifiers

I am write my code on linux and use gcc compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main () {
        printf("Data Types                  Size(bytes)\n");
        printf("=======================================\n");
        printf("char                        %2d\n", sizeof(char));
        printf("unsigned char               %2d\n", sizeof(unsigned char));
        printf("signed char                 %2d\n", sizeof(signed char));
        printf("int                         %2d\n", sizeof(int));
        printf("unsigned int                %2d\n", sizeof(unsigned int));
        printf("unsigned long int           %2d\n", sizeof(unsigned long int));
        printf("unsigned short int          %2d\n", sizeof(unsigned short int));
        printf("signed int                  %2d\n", sizeof(signed int));
        printf("short int                   %2d\n", sizeof(short int));
        printf("signed short int            %2d\n", sizeof(signed short int));
        printf("long int                    %2d\n", sizeof(long int));
        printf("signed long int             %2d\n", sizeof(signed long int));
        printf("float                       %2d\n", sizeof(float));
        printf("double                      %2d\n", sizeof(double));
        printf("long double                 %2d\n", sizeof(long double));
}
```

then compiled it show crash detected.

[image: output::]

Comment: `void main ()`...upgrade your book

Comment: avoid attaching external links

Comment: `%2d` --> `%2zu` or `sizeof(Type)` --> `(int)sizeof(Type)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  now i can solve this problem. but %2zu it's not work, i don't know why, then i use %2d and rewrite sizeof(Type) to (int)sizeof(Type). Thank you very much.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: _%2zu it's not work_ Use option of `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` yields a result of type `size_t`, You must use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.

Using mismatched type of arguments, (ex: `%d` which expects an `int` with result of `sizeof` which needs a `%zu`) invokes  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After that, `void main ()` is a pretty obsolete signature for a hosted environment, you should at at least use `int main (void)` to be conforming.

That said, I believe, *your program* did not *crash*, you did not run the binary, you were just in process of compiling that and the compiler has emitted warnings for your own good. Thanks for not ignoring them.